# How do I have code run after an executable is closed

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I want to back up my files after a windows program closes.
Pseudo Code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from dirsync import sync

program = '<prgm.exe Path>'
localDir = '<source Path>'
remoteDir = '<target Path>'

sync(remoteDir, localDir, 'sync', create = True, force = True)

subprocess.Popen([program])

while(program.isRunning()):<wait>

sync(sourceDir, targetDir, 'sync', create = True, force = True)
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` purpose is to have a non-blocking call. Use `os.system` instead to make it a blocking call.

Comment: I suggest avoiding `os.system()` as much as possible. `subprocess.Popen` is usually a better choice. You can call [`Popen.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) if you want to wait for the process to finish. The latter also supports timeouts.

Comment: What I've found to work is: 
`pClosed = subprocess.run(program)

if(pClosed):
    sync(sourceDir, targetDir, 'sync', verbose=True)
    print('Sync Complete')`